# Connection refused | Docker & ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I’m trying to connect to an ssh server from a docker container lifted by docker-compose.

On my localhost, I have enabled the port to use with **"ufw allow 4222"**, I have placed port 4222 in my docker-compose.yml file.

I have also added the public key of my localhost to the container and to the authorized keys of the server, the problem is that it keeps failing me, someone knows that more I can check or take into account? thank you.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
      hermes:
              depends_on:
                      - mongodb
              build:
                      context: ./hermes-app/
              container_name: hermes
              tty: true
              ports:
                      - "5000:5000"
                      - "4222"
              environment:
                           - SLACK_CLIENT_ID=${SLACK_CLIENT_ID}
                           - SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=${SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET}
                           - SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET=${SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET}
                           - SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN=${SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN}
                           - SSH_HOST=${SSH_HOST}
                           - SSH_USER=${SSH_USER}
                           - SSH_PORT=${SSH_PORT}
              networks:
                      - netrmes
```

Error:

```
root@6d55aa960f46:/hermes-app# ssh root@my_server -p 4222
ssh: connect to host my_server port 4222: Connection refused
```

Comment: Does the container have a valid network configuration? Can you ping the host? Can you access anything else outside the container? What is port 4222? Does the SSH daemon listen on port 4222? Add more details.

Answer (score 0):

So you try to ssh from the container to your host system. The container knows nothing about my_server if it is not in netrmes network. You could use `host` network and then

```
ssh root@localhost -p 4222
```